# Are the Carrier IQ daemons installed on iOS devices other than iPhones?

Tags: ios, privacy

For iOS 5, are either of the Carrier IQ daemons installed as part of the base software on any non phone device image such as the iPad, iPod Touch or Apple TV ?

On iPhones (iOS 5) these programs are /usr/bin/awd_ice2 or /usr/bin/awd_ice3

If yes, what causes them to run and to where does their data get stored or forwarded?

---

I am aware of the work [@chpwn](https://twitter.com/#!/chpwn) is doing and publishing on the [chpwn blog](http://blog.chpwn.com/) but that is iPhone specific so far. I'm looking for hard evidence that the software is or isn't on the base OS for non-phone devices as well as if they actually generate local log files (presumably only when the collect diagnostic data switch is turned on since on iOS that is an opt-in service that does let you know data will be collected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a quick check on my iPod4,1 running iOS 5.0.1. Those two binaries are not present in that folder. However, I have seen mentions of IQ in other parts of the system such as var/wireless/Library/Logs/awd (empty) and var/root/Library/Logs/awd (empty) and com.apple.iqagent.plist in var/mobile/Library/Preferences. The only value in that plist is DiagnosticsAllowed = false. I would conclude that Carrier IQ is not present on 4th Generation iPod Touches running iOS 5.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Well tauw has done some research on this: http://www.tuaw.com/2011/11/30/carrier-iq-references-found-in-ios-5-probably-benign/

But better yet is te read this: http://www.xydo.com/toolbar/41016399?subject_id=1004
It talks about all version of iOS 3 and up may include the Carrier QI software.

Comment: The research is specific to iPhone 4 and refers to the chpwn blog that also just discusses iPhones - I'm hoping people with actual jailbroken devices can confirm that the software is really there and perhaps look over their log files to let us know if it ever runs and what it's logging. Thanks for the links, though :-)

Answer (score -1):

According to the [chpwn blog](http://blog.chpwn.com/post/13572216737), answer is yes it's installed bUt keylogging not activated. Only Windows Mobile 7 doesn't have it AFATK!

Comment: The chpwn blog entry you link is very much addressed at iPhone OS and doesn't speak to iPad (WiFi or 3G / 1 or 2) as well as the iPod Touch models. Let's stick to iOS here as it's clear the Carrier IQ software on other platforms operates very much differently than on iOS.